# Why hasn't Peter Higgs solved the Yang-Mills prize problem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, higgs, yang-mills, confinement

The Higgs mechanism gets rid of the mass gap problem, and it's been experimentally proven, so why is there still a problem?

Why are [the million dollars still up for grabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems)?

Comment: Well it's an objective decision from the people who give out the million dollars. What's their reasoning?

Comment: Have you read [this description of the problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang–Mills_existence_and_mass_gap)? “For example, in the case of G=SU(3)—the strong nuclear interaction—the winner must prove that glueballs have a lower mass bound, and thus cannot be arbitrarily light.”  Does that follow from Peter Higgs’ work? I don’t think it does.

Comment: In what way do you imagine that the Higgs mechanism "gets rid of the mass gap problem"?

Answer (score 13):

The standard model Higgs particle has a weak charge, but no color charge. As a result it generates as mass gap in electroweak theory (masses for the W and Z), but not in QCD (no gluon mass). However, we know that QCD (even pure QCD, without fermions) does have a mass gap: Glueballs are heavy. The millenium prize problem asks why that is.

Answer (score 4):

The mass gap problem specifically asks for a work which succeeds in mathematically defining the QFT in a rigorous fashion:

> Prove that for any compact simple gauge group G, a non-trivial quantum Yang–Mills theory exists on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and has a mass gap $\Delta > 0$. Existence includes establishing axiomatic properties at least as strong as those cited in Streater & Wightman (1964), Osterwalder & Schrader (1973) and Osterwalder & Schrader (1975).

The work of Higgs does not even attempt to use these rigorous methods of mathematical physics.

Comment: Higgs' mechanism is not hard to handle rigorously.  It was largely done in the early 80s.  No prize for that.